# Can I create a shape in CSS (a pencil) without it acting weirdly when I try to rotate it?

Tags: css, css-transforms, css-shapes

I'm trying to create an image that looks like a pencil in CSS, which I think I've done OK, but it acts weirdly when I try to rotate it with "transform: rotate(-45deg);". I thought it would just rotate on an axis somewhere inside the original image, but it not only rotates the pencil, it also moves it a long way from its original position in a huge arc, which makes me think that the axis point is no longer inside the original image. (Just uncomment the "transform" rule at the end of the block of CSS included here to see what I mean.) And if you use a positive value – like 45deg – it rotates entirely off the page and you can't see the pencil.

I also tried to create various parts of the pencil using ::before and ::after pseudo elements, but then it rotated the main element but left the pseudo elements behind.

You can see it at
`enter code here`https://codepen.io/HorrieGrump/pen/GRmvJbV

This is my first-ever post, so pls forgive me if I've breached any rule (and reprimand politely). Thanks

```
<section class="pencil">
  <div class="cap"></div>
  <div class="tube"></div>
  <div class="space"></div>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
</section>



body {
  background: antiquewhite;
}

/**********************   FIRST PENCIL         *********************/

/* This is the ROUNDED SEMICIRCLE on top of the body of the pencil*/

.cap {
  height: 20px;
  width: 40px;
  border-top-left-radius: 40px;
  border-top-right-radius: 40px;
  background-color: gray;
}

/* This is the BODY of the pencil*/

.tube {
  height: 100px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: gray;
  margin-top: -1px;
}

/* This is the "empty" SPACE between body of the pencil and the tip of the pencil*/
.space {
  height: 20px;
  width: 40px;
  border-top-left-radius: 40px;
  border-top-right-radius: 40px;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  margin-top: -8px;
}


/* This is the TIP of the pencil*/
.triangle {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 25px solid transparent;
  border-right: 25px solid transparent;
  border-top: 40px solid gray;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: -6px;
}

/* This is a container to group all the parts of the pencil*/
section.pencil {
  margin-top: 8rem;
  margin-bottom: 17rem;
/*  transform: rotate(-45deg);*/
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `<section>` is a block element by default, it stretches to the full available width of the parent (see the yellow background in the example).

To make the container fit the content, you need to: make it inline-block (property `display: inline-block`) or add the property `width: min-content`.

I think you also want the pen to revolve not around the center, but around its tip. Just add `transform-origin: center bottom`.

```css
body { background: antiquewhite; }

/**********************   FIRST PENCIL         *********************/

/* This is the ROUNDED SEMICIRCLE on top of the body of the pencil*/
.cap {
  height: 20px;
  width: 40px;
  border-top-left-radius: 40px;
  border-top-right-radius: 40px;
  background-color: gray;
}

/* This is the BODY of the pencil*/
.tube {
  height: 100px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: gray;
  margin-top: -1px;
}

/* This is the "empty" SPACE between body of the pencil and the tip of the pencil*/
.space {
  height: 20px;
  width: 40px;
  border-top-left-radius: 40px;
  border-top-right-radius: 40px;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  margin-top: -8px;
}

/* This is the TIP of the pencil*/
.triangle {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 25px solid transparent;
  border-right: 25px solid transparent;
  border-top: 40px solid gray;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: -6px;
}

/* This is a container to group all the parts of the pencil*/
section.pencil {
  margin-top: 8rem;
  margin-bottom: 17rem;
  
  background-color: #fa08;
  transition: 1s ease;
}
section.pencil:hover { transform: rotate(45deg); }

/* Only for example */ input,label{position:fixed}label:nth-of-type(1){top:10px;left:10px}label:nth-of-type(2){top:10px;left:200px}label:nth-of-type(3){top:30px;left:35px}label:nth-of-type(4){top:30px;left:225px}input:nth-of-type(1){top:10px;left:160px}input:nth-of-type(2){top:10px;left:280px}input:nth-of-type(3){top:30px;left:10px}input:nth-of-type(4){top:30px;left:200px}#d-ib:checked~section.pencil{display:inline-block}#w-mc:checked~section.pencil{width:min-content}#to:checked~section.pencil{transform-origin:50% 100%}
```

```html
<label for="d-b">display: block (default)</label><input type="radio" name="display" id="d-b" checked><label for="d-ib">inline-block</label><input type="radio" name="display" id="d-ib"><input type="checkbox" id="w-mc"><label for="w-mc">width: min-content</label><input type="checkbox" id="to"><label for="to">transform-origin: 50% 100% (default = 50% 50%)</label>

<section class="pencil">
  <div class="cap"></div>
  <div class="tube"></div>
  <div class="space"></div>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks, UModel and AHaworth, for your useful and helpful answers. Strangely, I figured out the "display: inline-block" thing shortly after posting this question (but only because of luck and trial and error ... not innate genius!). But it certainly helped to get your answers and see that people more capable than me came up with this answer too. I also realise now that a <div> would have made more sense than <section>. Let me know if I've failed to give credit where it's due.

Comment: @Horrie: I am glad if my answer was useful to you. By the way, `<section>` and `<div>` are equally block elements, so there will be no difference.

Comment: Yes, both <section> and <div> are block elements, but I think the especially persnickety HTML experts say that <section> should be used to group stuff that's "semantically meaningful", maybe like a group of articles or something like that? Given that it's just an image of a pencil, I didn't think it was semantically meaningful. But yes, in the end,  both <section> and <div> have the same effect in this example.

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at your section element - it groups the bits of the pencil together fine, but give it a background color and you'll see something like this:

[image]

However, give it for example `display: inline-block` and it will have the width you expect (i.e. defined by the pencil). Now when you rotate it it does what you expect (the transform-origin defaults to center).

```css
body {
  background: antiquewhite;
}

/**********************   FIRST PENCIL         *********************/

/* This is the ROUNDED SEMICIRCLE on top of the body of the pencil*/

.cap {
  height: 20px;
  width: 40px;
  border-top-left-radius: 40px;
  border-top-right-radius: 40px;
  background-color: gray;
}

/* This is the BODY of the pencil*/

.tube {
  height: 100px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: gray;
  margin-top: -1px;
}

/* This is the "empty" SPACE between body of the pencil and the tip of the pencil*/
.space {
  height: 20px;
  width: 40px;
  border-top-left-radius: 40px;
  border-top-right-radius: 40px;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  margin-top: -8px;
}


/* This is the TIP of the pencil*/
.triangle {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 25px solid transparent;
  border-right: 25px solid transparent;
  border-top: 40px solid gray;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: -6px;
}

/* This is a container to group all the parts of the pencil*/
section.pencil {
  background-color: pink;
  margin-top: 8rem;
  margin-bottom: 17rem;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<section class="pencil">
  <div class="cap"></div>
  <div class="tube"></div>
  <div class="space"></div>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
</section>

<!-- <section class="pencil-2">
  <div class="cap-2"></div>
  <div class="tube-2"></div>
  <div class="space-2"></div>
  <div class="triangle-2"></div>
</section> -->
```